# Intellij idea import project

Tags: android, import, intellij-idea, project

How can I import an android project on intellij idea? When I go on Build-> Rebuild Project, I receive a message: "C:\Program" is not recognized as an internal or external command? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gues that you have your command in Program Files and IntelliJ have problem with " " space in path. Try move it to folder without spaces in name.